# How to detect the row and column number of cellwidget user clicked on QTableWidget in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

My objective is to set `multiple QPushButton` as `cellwidget` in a `QTableWidget` and whenever the user click on any of those buttons, it will print out the `Row` and `Column` number of table it is in.

So, for 1 `QPushButton`,

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

def CurrentPos():
    clickme = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
    index = table.indexAt(clickme.pos())
    if index.isValid():
        print (index.row(), index.column())
        
def AddValues():
    table.setRowCount(5)
    for i in range(5):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Click1')
        table.setCellWidget(i,1,button)
        button.clicked.connect(CurrentPos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
    table.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(330,250))

    table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
    table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QTableWidget.SelectRows)
    table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QTableWidget.NoSelection)
    table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
    table.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

    table.setColumnCount(3)
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['A','B','C'])
    table.setColumnWidth(0,50)
    table.setColumnWidth(1,200)
    table.show()

    AddValues()
    
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

When i click on each button, It will print out the rows and columns number just fine. But When I changed the function `AddValues` to accomodate multiple buttons:

```
def AddValues():
    table.setRowCount(5)
    for i in range(5):
        button1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Click1')
        button2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Click2')
        button3 = QtGui.QPushButton('Click3')
        
        button_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()       
        button_layout.addWidget(button1)
        button_layout.addWidget(button2)
        button_layout.addWidget(button3)
        
        buttons_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        buttons_widget.setLayout(button_layout)
        
        table.setCellWidget(i,1,buttons_widget)
        button1.clicked.connect(CurrentPos)
        button2.clicked.connect(CurrentPos)
        button3.clicked.connect(CurrentPos)
```

[image]

It no longer print out the correct row and column number anymore. Instead, It will just print either (0,0) or (0,1) depending on the position of the button.

I tried to print out the `QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()` and it gives me `<PyQt4.QtGui.QPushButton object at 0x014B56F0>` so as far as I understand, the focus widget is the actual `QPushButton` I am clicking instead of the `QWidget` named `buttons_widget`.

My only suspect is that `.pos()` method return the position relative to it's parent widget, which is `QWidget (buttons_widget)` rather than the `QTableWidget` itself. But I can't seems to find the documentation for `.pos()` method.

So, How can I modify my code so that whenever user click on any of 3 Pushbuttons, it print out the row and column number the button currently in.

I am using windows xp SP3 and Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
index = table.indexAt(clickme.parent().pos())
```

I should be checking the position of the parent `QWidget` rather than the `QPushButton`

Answer (score 7):

```
    buttonClicked = self.sender()
    index = self.table.indexAt(buttonClicked.pos())
    print index.row()
```

Answer (score 3):

Sams's answer works like a charm. RITZ XAVI, it works as follows:

1. buttonClicked = self.sender() - detects the widget that sends the signal
2. postitionOfWidget = buttonClicked.pos() - gets the x,y coordinate of this sender
3. index = self.table.indexAt(postitionOfWidget) - item in the qtablewidget with that coordinate
4. index.row() row of that item inside that qtablewidget

Sam, I can't thank you enough for this :-)